# How to push to external array from within a Prisma await async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, prisma

I'm trying to push an array to an external array that is called **buildings** from within a lodash **foreach loop** in a async await [Prisma.io](https://www.prisma.io/) request.

```
const buildings = [];
const companies = await prisma.user.findMany({
  where: {
    maintainers: {
      some: {
        id: req.user.id,
      },
    },
  },
});

console.log(companies);

_.forEach(companies, async (c) => {
  const edifici = await prisma.building.findMany({
    where: {
      TU: {
        some: {
          TU: {
            id: c.id,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  });


  console.log(edifici);

  buildings.push(...edifici);
});

console.log(buildings);
```

the result of the fist log `console.log(companies)` do log the companies needed.
the result of the second log `console.log(edifici)` do log the buildings that belongs to che companies in the for loop.

However when I try to push the result of the **edifici** await request into the **buildings** array which has been declared outside the foor loop the log does return an empty array.

How to push the result of the await request into the **buildings** array?

Comment: at very least you need an async enumerator - something like: for (let item of items) { await callPrims(item).then(addToYourArray); }. much better solution though would be to find a way to pass an array of building Ids into a single awaited Prism call. Lastly underscore provides with no real value in you scenario if at all these days.

Comment: Any top level code (for example `console.log(buildings)`) will execute *before* an async operation completes, no matter what you do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @RobinZigmond actually I don't know how to implement it with prisma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround to find out all buildings belonging to UU users via prisma:

```
const buildings = await prisma.building.findMany({
  where: {
    TU: {
      some: {
        TU: {
          maintainers: {
            some: {
              id: req.user.id,
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```